# Finding the Expected value of a Pareto distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given a Pareto distribution as $$f\left( x,\theta \right) =\frac{\alpha \beta ^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha +1}},\ x>\beta $$

**Question**: Why the expectation of $x$ of Pareto distribution is written as,

$$E\left( x \right) =\int_{\beta}^{\infty}{\alpha \beta ^{\alpha}x^{-\alpha}dx}$$

I guess it should be,

$$E\left( x \right) =\int_{\beta}^{\infty}{\alpha \beta ^{\alpha}x^{-\alpha -1}dx}$$

**Edit**: I guess because $E(x)=\int_{\beta}^{\infty} x\cdot f(x) dx$. So, $x$ gets cancelled with one $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: So, did you answer your own question, or was there something else you needed help with?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor. Thank you Mr. Robert. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous random variable $X$, we have by definition $\mathsf EX=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$. It follows for $X\sim\operatorname{Pareto}(\alpha,\beta)$ that
$$
\mathsf EX
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \alpha\beta^\alpha x^{-\alpha-1}\mathbf 1_{[\beta,\infty)}(x)\,\mathrm dx
=\alpha\beta^\alpha\int_\beta^\infty x^{-\alpha}\,\mathrm dx
=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}
$$
if $\alpha>1$ and $\mathsf EX=\infty$ otherwise.